# ASP: My data field is null since the 2nd Page_Load()

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code_behind is:

```
public partial class Question2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private DataTable table;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            //And pull the data from my DB to the table
        }
    }
```

I am intend to store my data (the 'table') in the class's field BUT after I clicked on any button of my page. I found that the Page_Load() is called again and my all data fields has gone. They're 'null'.

I'm really confuse what happen O_O. I just needed to store my table for later use. But why they're lost ? When does it lost ? Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, each request to the server will instantiate (new) the page class, so on your second page load you've got a fresh new object, not the one you had on the first request.

You could store your data either in [the Application state dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) if it shared among all users or [the Session state dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) if it isn't.

```
// Store it:
Application["myTable"] = ...;

// Get it back on a new request:
DataTable table = (DataTable)Application["myTable"];
```